# Visual Studio Code Не работает Javascript с Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

у меня очень странная проблема, и я уже не знаю как ее решить. Решил в один вечер я перейти на Visual Studio Code и начать изучать javascript, установил Node.js и сразу после этого меня постигла такая вот проблема, после того как я пишу код в файле, нажимаю f5 и выбираю средой Node.js у меня выскакивает такая проблема:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\frank.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'd:/����������������/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/bootloader.bundle.js'
Require stack:
- internal/preload
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at Module._preloadModules (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1277:12)
    at loadPreloadModules (internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js:439:5)
    at prepareMainThreadExecution (internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js:71:3)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:7:1 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'internal/preload' ]
}
```

Comment: попробуйте установить VS Code в папку, пусть которой не содержит русских букв и не такой длинный

Comment: @t0lik Спасибо, не знал что проблема так легко фиксится, теперь вроде все работает

Comment: а вам Error: Cannot find module 'd:/����������������/Microsoft VS Code/resources/ не показалось странным?)

Comment: @Vearodev Показалось, но у меня до этой ошибки было еще миллион ошибок которые я успешно решил, и я думал что сменю название папки если не останется выбора)